# Splitting Bot Records from Chatter Records

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, chat

I have raw chat bot transcripts, and before doing any sentiment analysis, I would like to separate Bot records from Chatter records.

Data is already in a dataframe, and looks like the following:

```
Conversation_ID | Transcript
abcdef | BOT: Some text. CHATTER: Some text. BOT: Some text. BOT: Some text. CHATTER: Some text. BOT: Some text. BOT: Some text.
```

The result should look like:

```
Conversation_ID | Transcript_BOT | Transcript_CHATTER
abcdef | Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. | Some text. Some text.
```

Comment: Yes, basically splitting overall transcript into two parts based on origination - bot or chatter.

Comment: can you print `df.to_dict` and post the values above? your data structure is not clear to me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm sorry. To clarify, currently the entire conversation for each of the instances is stored as one long string with pointers to BOT or CHATTER, and I would like to have two columns instead - one with all BOT messages, and the other with all CHATTER messages. Thus, the output should now contain three columns instead of two

Comment: Ah okay, that's quite doable, is 'abcdef |' a row or column ?

Comment: abcdef is a Conversation_ID for the first observation here

Comment: I provided a simplified example of how the data structure looks like. Here it is separated with pipes, but in my code it is a Pandas dataframe with two series - one for Conversation_ID, and the other for Transcript (both are strings)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly,

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='|')
df['Transcript'] = df['Conversation_ID'].str.split(':',expand=True)[1] # split by delim.
df['Conversation_ID'] = df['Conversation_ID'].str.split(':',expand=True)[0]
print(df)
    Conversation_ID Transcript
0   abcdef  None
1   BOT Some text.
2   CHATTER Some text.
3   BOT Some text.
4   BOT Some text.
5   CHATTER Some text.
6   BOT Some text.
7   BOT Some text.
```

and for your intended result :

```
new_df = (pd.crosstab(df['Conversation_ID'].iloc[0],
         df['Conversation_ID'].iloc[1:],
         values=df['Transcript']
        ,aggfunc='sum')).rename_axis('')
print(new_df)


Conversation_ID     BOT          CHATTER
abcdef              Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. S...    Some text. Some text.
```

Comment: Thank for you help! Apparently, I needed to be more clear. Please find my edited question above.

Comment: There are only two rows and two columns in my sample dataframe. First row is column names, and the second row is the only observation here -> conversation id followed by a very long string that contains entire conversation script.

Comment: Ah got it! I will do it first thing tomorrow morning, wife's banned me from the laptop!